# IPython notebook custom button icons

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm looking to add a new button to ipython notebook with a custom icon.

Starting from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20290369/ipython-notebook-toolbar-customize), I know I can change around the icons of a custom button using `custom.js`. However it seems i'm limited to the available icons in [fontawesome](http://fontawesome.io/3.2.1/icons/). Is it possible to get custom button icons?

My understanding is that `fontawesome` uses `svg` format, and I found this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426172/add-custom-icons-to-font-awesome),
describing the process for fontawesome, however the `HTML` that IPython uses is a bit different.

The question remains how can I point my `icon.svg` file to be read by `IPython notebook`, below is a minimal example in `custom.js` to add a button, along with the relevant `HTML` produced.

**Minimal button example in custom.js:**

```
IPython.toolbar.add_buttons_group([
{
     'label': 'Create TOC',
     'icon' : 'icon-list', 
  'callback': function(){
    }
}]);
```

The line `'icon' : 'icon-list',` correlates to one of the many icons fontawesome has [here](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/)

**IPython HTML for the above button:**

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn" title="Create TOC">
        <i class="icon-list"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

Is there a way to customize an icon in `IPython notebook` without having to add it to `fontawesome`?

Comment: Check this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20290369/ipython-notebook-toolbar-customize

Comment: @VyacheslavYudanov I'm already following this thanks for posting thou!

Answer (score 1):

Technically it is doable but slightly more involve that what you would expect. 
You would need to create your own version of a webfont using smth like icomoon, or fontforge, export-it to a font and css file (the css file probably want to use a private-plane area of  unicode which is different than what FA uses).

As IPython 2.x and above support requirejs, you can load the custom font and css with some tricks. Then supposing you are using the `cf` prefix, you can just use `icon:'cf-awesomeicon'`.

So what you want to know first is :

- How do I create a custom webfont. The rest is (almost) piece of cake.

Then see [here](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions/tree/master/styling) for notebook extensions that load css (loading the css should pull the font automatically).