# How to hide code from cells in ipython notebook visualized with nbviewer?

Tags: javascript, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have an ipython/jupyter notebook that I visualize using NBviewer.

How can I hide all the code from the notebook rendered by NBviewer, so that only the output of code (e.g. plots and tables) and the markdown cells are shown?

Comment: There is still not an existing button for this in the default UI (Feb 2016).  IMHO this is really really annoying.   This is on the list of features that will be implemented: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/534  That is great.  I look forward to it.

Comment: Please have a look below at Noahs answer. With the inclusion of a TemplateExporter this problem is solved independent of the output format. At time of writing Noahs answer supersedes harshils answer (which was a good solution bevor the TemplateExporter).

Comment: I created a [`Mercury`](https://github.com/mljar/mercury) framework to make it easy to share notebooks with non-technical users. You can parametrize notebook with interactive widgets and serve as a web app. There is no UI coding, just add a YAML header. There is a `show-code` parameter to hide the code in a notebook easily.

Answer (score 293, accepted):

```
from IPython.display import HTML

HTML('''<script>
code_show=true; 
function code_toggle() {
 if (code_show){
 $('div.input').hide();
 } else {
 $('div.input').show();
 }
 code_show = !code_show
} 
$( document ).ready(code_toggle);
</script>
<form action="javascript:code_toggle()"><input type="submit" value="Click here to toggle on/off the raw code."></form>''')
```

Comment: Worked for me on iPython 3.1.0 if I put it inside code cell. I replaced the `<form action ... >  ... </form>` with simple HTML like `The raw code for this IPython notebook is by default hidden for easier reading.To toggle on/off the raw code, click <a href="javascript:code_toggle()">here</a>.`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! See my answer if you need the button to be hidden and the ability to hide or show certain code blocks like Rstudio.

Comment: Thanks, this works and with 'saving to html' too. Recommend placing this in it's own cell at the top of the notebook.

Comment: if you add the attribute accesskey="h" to the input element you can then do the show hide with alt-h (in chrome at least)

Comment: How would you change this so it doesn't even show the button, it just hides the code?

Comment: How can I control the dimensions of the Toggle Button ?

Comment: @Harlekuin HTML('''<script>
code_show=true; 
function code_toggle() {

 $('div.input').hide();

} 
$( document ).ready(code_toggle);
</script>
''')

Comment: Does it work only for a specific version of Ipython? It used to work for me, but then I update some packages (including Ipython) and this doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @Harlekuin you can just remove the <form ...></form> tag. keep in mind, however, that you cannot see the code cells afterward anymore and would need to reload the notebook again ;)

Comment: This used to work great with notebooks downloaded as HTML, but now I can see the button but it doesn't do anything. Am running nb server 6.1.4; Python 3.8.5; IPython 7.19.0.

Comment: This does not work for me with downloaded html anymore; what am I missing?

Comment: Yep, not work now!!!

Answer (score 137):

This is now possible directly from nbconvert as of version [5.2.1](http://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html#global-content-filtering): content can be filtered using the built-in [template exporter exclude options](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config_options.html?highlight=TemplateExporter.exclude). For example:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to pdf --TemplateExporter.exclude_input=True my_notebook.ipynb
```

will exclude the "input code" cells, ie the code itself. [Similar options](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config_options.html?highlight=TemplateExporter.exclude) exist to exclude prompts, markdown cells, or outputs, or both inputs and outputs.

(These options should work irrespective of output format.)

Comment: this is the best answer

Comment: Where does the .pdf export save by default?

Comment: Same folder as .ipython notebook. Use argument '--output NotebookNoCode' to rename the file.

Comment: Is this supposed to run in the notebook ?

Comment: @were_cat no, this is a shell command used to export the .ipynb notebook file; in this example, it gets converted to pdf

Comment: hmm by looking I don't how to do this. Where should I run the line of code to exclude code input?

Comment: @skurp jupyter nbconvert --to pdf --no-input your_file_name.ipynb --output-dir='./_directory_relative_from_path'

Answer (score 22):

I would use `hide_input_all` from **nbextensions** (https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions). Here's how:

1. Find out where your IPython directory is:

   ```
   from IPython.utils.path import get_ipython_dir
   print get_ipython_dir()
   ```
2. Download **nbextensions** and move it to the IPython directory.
3. Edit your *custom.js* file somewhere in the IPython directory (mine
   was in *profile_default/static/custom*) to be similar to the
   *custom.example.js* in the *nbextensions* directory.
4. Add this line to *custom.js*:

   ```
   IPython.load_extensions('usability/hide_input_all')
   ```

IPython Notebook will now have a button to toggle code cells, no matter the workbook.

Comment: Just tried this - it seems to help with hiding the code cells while editing a notebook, although when saving the notebook to html (i.e. rendering to nbviewer) the code cells still appear.

Comment: @VivekGani just a quick note that you can keep the hidden cells hidden in the exported html using the template provided with the same repo, see the [relevant doc page](http://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/hide_input/readme.html#exporting-with-nbconvert) (also, see [this relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24062013/4063051))

Answer (score 18):

I wrote some code that accomplishes this, and adds a button to toggle visibility of code.

The following goes in a code cell at the top of a notebook:

```
from IPython.display import display
from IPython.display import HTML
import IPython.core.display as di # Example: di.display_html('<h3>%s:</h3>' % str, raw=True)

# This line will hide code by default when the notebook is exported as HTML
di.display_html('<script>jQuery(function() {if (jQuery("body.notebook_app").length == 0) { jQuery(".input_area").toggle(); jQuery(".prompt").toggle();}});</script>', raw=True)

# This line will add a button to toggle visibility of code blocks, for use with the HTML export version
di.display_html('''<button onclick="jQuery('.input_area').toggle(); jQuery('.prompt').toggle();">Toggle code</button>''', raw=True)
```

You can see [an example of how this looks in NBviewer here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/gist.github.com/masnick/d6a1af14812c0c4b3314/raw/f7a5abfb6475e683a90b4ac3491d134ef604e460/test.ipynb).

**Update:** This will have some funny behavior with Markdown cells in Jupyter, but it works fine in the HTML export version of the notebook.

Comment: This works on code cells, but if you have markdown cells it does something odd. It shows the **markdown *as markdown***, and then shows the same content--but formatted--below.

Comment: I just figured out that the only thing wrong is the node specification. Instead of `'.input_area'` and `'.prompt'`, use `'div.input'` and it works like a charm! So to recap, substitute `jQuery("div.input").toggle();` in place of `jQuery('.input_area').toggle(); jQuery('.prompt').toggle();`. @Max Masnick, could you fix your answer?

Comment: Using the "div.input" as the node selection works as long as you don't interact with the markdown cells, but I just figured out that if you do interact with the markdown cells you might get some funky behavior. For example, if you double-click a markdown cell then it gets hidden entirely. So as-is, my tweak to Max's solution is fine for generating HTML to share with others, but not for subsequently interacting too much with it.

Comment: Yeah, so I noticed the same thing you did with the Markdown cells getting all jacked up. It works fine in the HTML export, which is where I use it. I'll edit the answer to note this.

Comment: To remove the right-space leftover from the removal of ".prompt" simply add this code to the end of  the above code.

`CSS = """#notebook div.output_subarea {
    max-width:100%;"""`


`HTML('<style>{}</style>'.format(CSS))`.
This is very useful for printing.

Comment: From Scott H's answer, I found that using '.input' instead of 'div.input' worked fine with the markdown.

Comment: "*This will have some funny behavior*", it's not so funny as cells disappear completely with no other way to restore them than to restart the kernel. While the solution is easy, I wonder what can happen when you further interact with the cells when one is hidden, e.g. if you select previous and next cells and delete them. Chances are the hidden cell will be deleted without warning. That apart, nice solution anyway.

Answer (score 16):

The newest IPython notebook version do not allow executing javascript in markdown cells anymore, so adding a new markdown cell with the following javascript code will not work anymore to hide your code cells (refer to [this link](http://blog.nextgenetics.net/?e=99))

Change ~/.ipython/profile_default/static/custom/custom.js as below:

```
code_show=true;
function code_toggle() {
 if (code_show){
 $('div.input').hide();
 } else {
 $('div.input').show();
 }
 code_show = !code_show
}

$([IPython.events]).on("app_initialized.NotebookApp", function () {
  $("#view_menu").append("<li id=\"toggle_toolbar\" title=\"Show/Hide code cells\"><a href=\"javascript:code_toggle()\">Toggle Code Cells</a></li>")
});
```

Comment: Strangely that solution did not work for me as iPython view menu remains unchanged. (iPython 3.1.0) Your solution inspired me to look further and find a very similar solution by [p3trus](https://gist.github.com/p3trus/5262026) that added a button instead of a menu and it did work.

Comment: @akhmed Maybe your can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/29851084/1914781. It's a difference question but it helpful for you!

Comment: This is for jupyter. You can still use RAW rather than markdown, Looks Jupyter no longer uses JQuery. Include script-JQuery from your favorite CDN. Change "$('div.input')" to "$('div.jp-Cell-inputArea')" and it works as originally designed.

Answer (score 14):

This can be done using an IPython `ToggleButton` widget and a little bit of JavaScript. The following code should be placed into a code cell at the top of the document:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display, HTML

javascript_functions = {False: "hide()", True: "show()"}
button_descriptions  = {False: "Show code", True: "Hide code"}


def toggle_code(state):

    """
    Toggles the JavaScript show()/hide() function on the div.input element.
    """

    output_string = "<script>$(\"div.input\").{}</script>"
    output_args   = (javascript_functions[state],)
    output        = output_string.format(*output_args)

    display(HTML(output))


def button_action(value):

    """
    Calls the toggle_code function and updates the button description.
    """

    state = value.new

    toggle_code(state)

    value.owner.description = button_descriptions[state]


state = False
toggle_code(state)

button = widgets.ToggleButton(state, description = button_descriptions[state])
button.observe(button_action, "value")

display(button)
```

This creates the following button to toggle showing/hiding the code for the Jupyter Notebook, defaulted to the "hide" state:

[image: Hide code state]

When set to the "show" state, you can then see the code for the Jupyter Notebook:

[image: Show code state]

As an aside, while much of this code should be placed at the beginning of the Notebook, the location of the toggle button is optional. Personally, I prefer to keep it at the bottom of the document. To do so, simply move the `display(button)` line to a separate code cell at the bottom of the page:

[image: Relocated toggle button]

Answer (score 12):

## A script to show/hide Jupyter Notebook code cells both in edit interface and in the exported html

Just put this code in the first cell and run it:

```js
%%HTML 
<script>
    function luc21893_refresh_cell(cell) {
        if( cell.luc21893 ) return;
        cell.luc21893 = true;
        console.debug('New code cell found...' );
        
        var div = document.createElement('DIV');            
        cell.parentNode.insertBefore( div, cell.nextSibling );
        div.style.textAlign = 'right';
        var a = document.createElement('A');
        div.appendChild(a);
        a.href='#'
        a.luc21893 = cell;
        a.setAttribute( 'onclick', "luc21893_toggle(this); return false;" );

        cell.style.visibility='hidden';
        cell.style.position='absolute';
        a.innerHTML = '[show code]';        
                
    }
    function luc21893_refresh() {                
        if( document.querySelector('.code_cell .input') == null ) {            
            // it apeears that I am in a exported html
            // hide this code
            var codeCells = document.querySelectorAll('.jp-InputArea')
            codeCells[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';
            codeCells[0].style.position = 'absolute';                        
            for( var i = 1; i < codeCells.length; i++ ) {
                luc21893_refresh_cell(codeCells[i].parentNode)
            }
            window.onload = luc21893_refresh;
        }                 
        else {
            // it apperas that I am in a jupyter editor
            var codeCells = document.querySelectorAll('.code_cell .input')
            for( var i = 0; i < codeCells.length; i++ ) {
                luc21893_refresh_cell(codeCells[i])
            }            
            window.setTimeout( luc21893_refresh, 1000 )
        }        
    }
    
    function luc21893_toggle(a) {
        if( a.luc21893.style.visibility=='hidden' ) {
            a.luc21893.style.visibility='visible';        
            a.luc21893.style.position='';
            a.innerHTML = '[hide code]';
        }
        else {
            a.luc21893.style.visibility='hidden';        
            a.luc21893.style.position='absolute';
            a.innerHTML = '[show code]';
        }
    }
    
    luc21893_refresh()
</script>
```

## Example in editor

[image: Example in editor]

## Example exported HTML

[image: Example Export]

Comment: is there a way to add tag to show code from some cells?

Comment: @SheeceGardazi, I uploaded a version to do that on my [github:lab104](https://github.com/lab104/python/tree/main/archived/2021-09-09-jupyter-content-focused). Actually, I do not use this anymore because jupyterlab implemented something similar.

Answer (score 8):

There is a nice solution provided 
[here](http://chris-said.io/2016/02/13/how-to-make-polished-jupyter-presentations-with-optional-code-visibility/) that works well for notebooks exported to HTML. The website even links back here to this SO post, but I don't see Chris's solution here! (Chris, where are you at?)

This is basically the same solution as the accepted answer from harshil, but it has the advantage of hiding the toggle code itself in the exported HTML. I also like that this approach avoids the need for the IPython HTML function.

To implement this solution, add the following code to a 'Raw NBConvert' cell at the top of your notebook:

```
<script>
  function code_toggle() {
    if (code_shown){
      $('div.input').hide('500');
      $('#toggleButton').val('Show Code')
    } else {
      $('div.input').show('500');
      $('#toggleButton').val('Hide Code')
    }
    code_shown = !code_shown
  }

  $( document ).ready(function(){
    code_shown=false;
    $('div.input').hide()
  });
</script>
<form action="javascript:code_toggle()">
  <input type="submit" id="toggleButton" value="Show Code">
</form>
```

Then simply export the notebook to HTML. There will be a toggle button at the top of the notebook to show or hide the code.

Chris also provides an example [here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/csaid/polished_notebooks/blob/master/notebook_polished.ipynb).

I can verify that this works in Jupyter 5.0.0

**Update**:
It is also convenient to show/hide the `div.prompt` elements along with the `div.input` elements. This removes the `In [##]:` and `Out: [##]` text and reduces the margins on the left.

Comment: would it be possible to use this code to selectively hide outputs with the click of a button? I.E. `$('div.output').next().hide('500');` to hide the next output? I have tried myself but can't get this to work.

Answer (score 7):

Convert cell to Markdown and use HTML5 `<details>` tag as in the example by `joyrexus`:

https://gist.github.com/joyrexus/16041f2426450e73f5df9391f7f7ae5f

````
## collapsible markdown?

<details><summary>CLICK ME</summary>
<p>

#### yes, even hidden code blocks!

```python
print("hello world!")
```

</p>
</details>
````

Comment: Such a simple, clean solution!

Answer (score 6):

```
jupyter nbconvert yourNotebook.ipynb --no-input --no-prompt
```

`jupyter nbconvert yourNotebook.ipynb`
This part of the code will take the latex file format of the jupyter notebook and converts it to a html

`--no-input` This is like a parameter we are saying during conversion that dont add any inputs : here the input to a cell is the code.. so we hide it

`--no-prompt` Here also we are saying, During conversion dont show any prompts form the code like errors or warnings in the final HTML file ) so that that html will have only the Text and the code output in the form of a report !!..

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Please add some explanation instead of simply anwering with a command.

Comment: Hi, jupyter nbconvert yourNotebook.ipynb ( This part of the code will take the latex file format of the jupyter notebook and converts it to a html )   --no-input   (This is like a parameter we are saying during conversion that dont add any inputs : here the input to a cell is the code.. so we hide it ) --no-prompt ( Here also we are saying, During conversion dont show any prompts form the code like errors or warnings in the final HTML file ) so that that html will have only the Text and the code output in the form of a report !!.. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 5):

For better display with printed document or a report, we need to remove the button as well, and the ability to show or hide certain code blocks. Here's what I use (simply copy-paste this to your first cell):

```
# This is a cell to hide code snippets from displaying
# This must be at first cell!

from IPython.display import HTML

hide_me = ''
HTML('''<script>
code_show=true; 
function code_toggle() {
  if (code_show) {
    $('div.input').each(function(id) {
      el = $(this).find('.cm-variable:first');
      if (id == 0 || el.text() == 'hide_me') {
        $(this).hide();
      }
    });
    $('div.output_prompt').css('opacity', 0);
  } else {
    $('div.input').each(function(id) {
      $(this).show();
    });
    $('div.output_prompt').css('opacity', 1);
  }
  code_show = !code_show
} 
$( document ).ready(code_toggle);
</script>
<form action="javascript:code_toggle()"><input style="opacity:0" type="submit" value="Click here to toggle on/off the raw code."></form>''')
```

Then in your next cells:

```
hide_me
print "this code will be hidden"
```

and

```
print "this code will be shown"
```

Comment: I'm guessing this doesn't work for the most recent versions / python 3?

Comment: Works with jupyter version 4.3.0 with Python version 3.6.1.

Comment: Thanks! Happy to say that this works with Jupyter notebook **5.3.1** as well. I'm using Python version **3.6.1**

Answer (score 5):

This will render an IPython notebook output. However, you will note be able to view the input code. You can copy a notebook, then add this code if needed to share with someone who does not need to view the code.

```
from IPython.display import HTML

HTML('''<script> $('div .input').hide()''')
```

Comment: @Rocketq use this - 

```from IPython.display import HTML

HTML('''<script> $('div.input').show()''')```

Answer (score 3):

Very easy solution using Console of the browser. You copy this into your browser console and hit enter:

```
$("div.input div.prompt_container").on('click', function(e){
    $($(e.target).closest('div.input').find('div.input_area')[0]).toggle();
});
```

[image: insert script into browser console]

Then you toggle the code of the cell simply by clicking on the number of cell input.

[image: cell number]

Comment: heyyy this is great!

Answer (score 2):

Many times, we need to hide some parts of codes while writing a long code.

Example: - Just on clicking "Code show/hide", we can hide 3 lines of codes.

[image]

So here is the function that you need to define for partially hiding few part of codes and then call it whenever you want to hide some code:

```
from IPython.display import HTML

def hide_toggle(for_next=False):
    this_cell = """$('div.cell.code_cell.rendered.selected')""" ; next_cell = this_cell + '.next()';
    toggle_text = 'Code show/hide'  # text shown on toggle link
    target_cell = this_cell ;  js_hide_current = '' 

    if for_next:
        target_cell = next_cell; toggle_text += ' next cell';
        js_hide_current = this_cell + '.find("div.input").hide();'
    js_f_name = 'code_toggle_{}'.format(str(random.randint(1,2**64)))

    html = """<script>
            function {f_name}() {{{cell_selector}.find('div.input').toggle(); }}
            {js_hide_current}
        </script>
        <a href="javascript:{f_name}()">{toggle_text}</a>
    """.format(f_name=js_f_name,cell_selector=target_cell,js_hide_current=js_hide_current, toggle_text=toggle_text )
    return HTML(html)
```

Once we are ready with function definition, our next task is very easy. Just we need to call the function to hide/show the code.

```
print("Function for hiding the cell")
hide_toggle()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution suggested by [p3trus](https://gist.github.com/p3trus/5262026):

```
$([IPython.events]).on('notebook_loaded.Notebook', function(){
    IPython.toolbar.add_buttons_group([
        {
             'label'   : 'toggle input cells',
             'icon'    : 'icon-refresh', 
             'callback': function(){$('.input').slideToggle()}
        }
    ]);
});
```

As described by [p3trus](https://gist.github.com/p3trus/5262026):
"[It] adds a button to the ipython notebook toolbar to hide/show the input code cell. To use it, you have to put the custom.js file in your `.ipython_<profile name>/static/custom/` folder, where  is the ipython profile in use."

My own comments: I verified this solution and it works with iPython 3.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://chris-said.io/2016/02/13/how-to-make-polished-jupyter-presentations-with-optional-code-visibility/) is a nice article (the same one @Ken posted) on how to polish up Jpuyter (the new IPython) notebooks for presentation. There are countless ways to extend Jupyter using JS, HTML, and CSS, including the ability to communicate with the notebook's python kernel from javascript. There are magic decorators for `%%HTML` and `%%javascript` so you can just do something like this in a cell by itself:

```
%%HTML
<script>
  function code_toggle() {
    if (code_shown){
      $('div.input').hide('500');
      $('#toggleButton').val('Show Code')
    } else {
      $('div.input').show('500');
      $('#toggleButton').val('Hide Code')
    }
    code_shown = !code_shown
  }

  $( document ).ready(function(){
    code_shown=false;
    $('div.input').hide()
  });
</script>
<form action="javascript:code_toggle()"><input type="submit" id="toggleButton" value="Show Code"></form>
```

I can also vouch Chris's methods work in jupyter 4.X.X.

Answer (score 1):

The code in original verified solution does not work anymore in latest JupyterLab 4.x.x

Try this code instead (tested in JupyterLab 4 and works):

```
# Special javascript code, that creates new BUTTON, which shows/hides all code.
# Button is visible also here in Python notebook, but really works and operates only in HTML export.

from IPython.display import HTML

HTML(
'''
<script>
    code_show = true;

    function code_toggle() {
        if (code_show) {
            document.querySelectorAll('.jp-CodeCell .jp-InputArea').forEach(function(el) {
               el.style.display = 'none';
            });
        } else {
            document.querySelectorAll('.jp-CodeCell .jp-InputArea').forEach(function(el) {
               el.style.display = 'block';
            });
        }
        code_show = !code_show
    }
</script>
<form action="javascript:code_toggle()">
    <input type="submit" value="Show / Hide code">
</form>
'''
)
```

Comment: Underrated answer. Much appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution also works in julia Jupyter/IJulia with the following modifications:

```
display("text/html", """<script>
code_show=true; 
function code_toggle() {
 if (code_show){
 \$("div.input").hide();
 } else {
 \$("div.input").show();
 }
 code_show = !code_show
} 
\$( document ).ready(code_toggle);
</script>
<form action="javascript:code_toggle()"><input type="submit" value="Click here to toggle on/off the raw code."></form>""")
```

note in particular:

- use the `display` function
- escape the `$` sign (otherwise seen as a variable)

Comment: I am confused how to get this working. Is an import statement needed and what type of box should the block be. A raw one or a code box?

Answer (score 0):

The problem I have with [@harshil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4244561/harshil)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28073228/4713169) is that it will not collapse hidden cells, leaving a somewhat ugly-looking empty space in their place (I'm using IPython 7.30.1 and nbconvert 6.3.0) [[example]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRngE.png).

This is because the `input` *div* is inside a wrapper, so when `input` is hidden, the wrapper doesn't collapse. (If you have no code cells without output, this won't be a problem for you, as when the `input` is hidden, it will collapse **inside** the wrapper, and therefore the `output` *div* will take up all the space).

Here's how you can do it (just put this in a cell):

```
from IPython.display import HTML

HTML('''<script>
    var code_show = true; 
    function code_toggle() {
         if (code_show) {
             $( 'div[class*="code_cell"]:not(:has(.output))' ).hide();
             $( 'div.input' ).hide();
         } else {
             $( 'div[class*="code_cell"]:not(:has(.output))' ).show();
             $( 'div.input' ).show();
         }
         code_show = !code_show;
    } 
    $( document ).ready(code_toggle);
    </script>
    To toggle on/off the raw code, click <a>href="javascript:code_toggle()">here</a>.''')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you work manually (no bulk-runs/bulk-exports), there is a quite simple solution: add the following code block & execute it

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML
HTML('<style>.input, .jp-InputArea {display: none !important}</style>')
```

Code will disappear both in the "normal" UI and in print preview / export to HTML. Clear the output of this one cell to bring the code back, done

Note that the code is still *there* just not visible, so only use this when you want to show (or export use print preview to generate a PDF. That PDF looks pretty decent now. Do not use it when you want to keep the code to yourself)

Answer (score -1):

With all the solutions above even though you're hiding the code, you'll still get the `[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x128514278>]` crap above your figure which you probably don't want.

If you actually want to get rid of the input rather than just hiding it, I think
 the cleanest solution is to save your figures to disk in hidden cells, and then just including the images in Markdown cells using e.g. `![Caption](figure1.png)`.

Comment: You can put `_ = plt.plot()` to not have it print `[<>]` crap

Comment: Placing a semicolon after the matplotlib plotting commands suppressed the unwanted output for me.

Answer (score -1):

Simple programmatic solution for exporting a notebook to HTML without the code cells (output only): add this code in a code cell of the notebook  `my_notebook.ipynb` you want to export:

```
import codecs
import nbformat
import time
from IPython.display import Javascript
from nbconvert import HTMLExporter

def save_notebook():
    display(
        Javascript("IPython.notebook.save_notebook()"),
        include=['application/javascript']
    )    

def html_export_output_only(read_file, output_file):
    exporter = HTMLExporter()
    exporter.exclude_input = True
    output_notebook = nbformat.read(read_file, as_version=nbformat.NO_CONVERT)
    output, resources = exporter.from_notebook_node(output_notebook)
    codecs.open(output_file, 'w', encoding='utf-8').write(output)


# save notebook to html
save_notebook()
time.sleep(1)
output_file = 'my_notebook_export.html'
html_export_output_only("my_notebook.ipynb", output_file)
```

Answer (score -2):

**(Paper) Printing or Saving as HTML**

For those of you wishing to print to paper the outputs the above answers alone seem not to give a nice final output. However, taking @Max Masnick's code and adding the following allows one to print it on a full A4 page.

```
from IPython.display import display
from IPython.display import HTML
import IPython.core.display as di

di.display_html('<script>jQuery(function() {if (jQuery("body.notebook_app").length == 0) { jQuery(".input_area").toggle(); jQuery(".prompt").toggle();}});</script>', raw=True)

CSS = """#notebook div.output_subarea {max-width:100%;}""" #changes output_subarea width to 100% (from 100% - 14ex)
HTML('<style>{}</style>'.format(CSS))
```

The reason for the indent is that the prompt section removed by Max Masnick means everything shifts to the left on output. This however did nothing for the maximum width of the output which was restricted to `max-width:100%-14ex;`. This changes the max width of the output_subarea to `max-width:100%;`.

Comment: Hi, I don't know the changes to make it work. It simply doesn't work for me. That's why the downvote.

Comment: Thanks - I'll take a look and try and update it so it does

Answer (score -2):

```
jupyter nbconvert testing.ipynb --to html --no-input
```