# Hide input cells by default in ipython notebook

Tags: javascript, startup

This is a related question to
[How to hide code from cells in ipython notebook visualized with nbviewer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934885/how-to-hide-code-from-cells-in-ipython-notebook-visualized-with-nbviewer/29218545#29218545)

While having an interactive toggle on one notebook works very well, I'd like all notebooks to hide all code cells upon launching the notebook server.  To that end, I was thinking of adding the js script that contains `div.input.hide()` to `custom.js`.  But this didn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

`$('div .input').hide()` might do.

Answer (score 0):

Also can try this, If an element has a display value of inline and is hidden then shown, it will once again be displayed inline.

```
$('div .input').css( "display", "none" );
```