# how to extract ipython output without code snippets

Tags: ipython

I want to run the ipython notebook and save the outputs as pdf so that I produce reports **without** the code snippet.
The behaviour I've observed is that the code is alway included.
Any ideas?

Comment: You may be interested in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934885/how-to-hide-code-from-cells-in-ipython-notebook-visualized-with-nbviewer).  It works for HTML, I need to install some stuff to test with PDFs but I'm doing that now.

Comment: No, sorry, that did not eliminate code hunks from the generated PDF.

Comment: You'd need to write a custom template for nbconvert: http://nbconvert.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customizing.html