# export notebook to pdf without code

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I have a large notebook with a lot of figures and text. I want to convert it to a html file. However, I don't want to export the code. I am using the following command

```
ipython nbconvert --to html notebook.ipynb
```

But this option also exports the code. Is there a way to convert the notebook to html without the code?

Comment: Do you want to export to PDF (re your title) or to HTML (re the body of your question)? or maybe both of them?

Comment: let's say both @gboffi

Comment: Could you please tell us whether there is a chance to accept one of those answers below?

Comment: There is built-in support for this in nbconvert. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50790330/

Comment: You should just need to pass the `--no-input` argument to `nbconvert`.

Comment: `jupyter nbconvert --no-input --to html notebook.ipynb`

Comment: Is there a plugin for this available??

Comment: The article with different approaches to [export notebook as PDF file](https://mljar.com/blog/jupyter-notebook-pdf/).

Answer (score 84, accepted):

I found [this](http://greg-ashton.physics.monash.edu/ipython-nbconvert-latex-template-to-hide-code.html)  article interesting it explains how to remove the input columns :

you have to create a template file named "hidecode.tplx"  in same directory as the notebook you want to convert and add those line in it :

```
    ((*- extends 'article.tplx' -*))

((* block input_group *))
    ((*- if cell.metadata.get('nbconvert', {}).get('show_code', False) -*))
        ((( super() )))
    ((*- endif -*))
((* endblock input_group *))
```

And after run this command it will use pdfLatex to convert the notebook  in pdf via latex:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to pdf --template hidecode Example.ipynb
```

or if you want to edit you can convert it to a .tex document and use pdfLatex to put it in pdf :

```
jupyter nbconvert --to latex --template hidecode Example.ipynb
```

**EDIT Sept 2018:**

`ipython nbconvert` is deprecated. It will be replaced by `jupyter nbconvert`: So we replace the command `ipython` with `jupyter`

**EDIT Feb 2021:**  (This is my best answer here,  so let me take care of it)

Following @Mrule comment adding --no-input flag will make it work without the template...

```
jupyter nbconvert --to latex --no-input Example.ipynb
```

PS: If you are getting issue saying :

> LaTeX error related to tcolorbox.sty not found

Please refer to [this guide](https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html) to update your tex installation and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59225719/latex-error-related-to-tcolorbox-sty-not-found)

Comment: this doesn't work for exporting to html... it complains that can't find the template

Comment: Doesn't work just like out of the box.

Comment: Seconded; can confirm that this does nothing, as of October 12 2020 on jupyter nbconvert version 6.0.7.

Comment: Can you please let us know what is not working? and how we can improve the answer? @MRule

Comment: It seems like nbconvert 6.07 just ignores whatever is being set in that template. But! There is now a better option: pass --no-input as a flag to jupyter nbconvert.

Comment: I tells me `
ValueError: No template sub-directory with name 'hidecode' found in the following paths:
 /home/sherif/.local/share/jupyter
 /home/sherif/notebooks/EDA/EDA/.venv/share/jupyter
 /usr/local/share/jupyter
 /usr/share/jupyter
`

Comment: The second option worked like a charm for me. Thanks

Comment: If that work don't foget to upvote @igorkf

Comment: This answer seems to be incomplete.

Comment: what is missing?

Comment: I tried this - (jupyter nbconvert --to html --no-input Example.ipynb )and it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 44):

I was seeking the same question in SO and finally turned out to a very straightforward way:

Assuming using Firefox(57) + Win7

1. Run Jupyter notebook and download the notebook in the browser: File->Download as->HTML and you will get a html page with code and output.
2. Open the exported HTML with browser and activate the browser console with key `F12`
3. Run following command in the console:

   ```
   document.querySelectorAll("div.input").forEach(function(a){a.remove()})
   ```
4. The code removes all input div DOM. Then `right mouse button` and chose "Save Page As" and Save the "Complete page" (not single page).
5. You will get a page with an associated folder in windows. Use a trick by zip the html page and then extract to unbind the associated. The folder is useless.
6. Now it is a single html page without code. You can re-distribute it or print it as PDF.

If you are not using Firefox or Windows, please adjust the above 3-6 steps.

Comment: Works for Chrome too!

Comment: Might seem crazy, but this is one-line simple and it works perfectly.  Thanks for digging this up!

Comment: I copied the command in the console as u said, but it yields `undefined` and nothing was removed

Comment: I think now is `document.querySelectorAll("div.jp-InputArea.jp-Cell-inputArea").forEach(function(a){a.remove()})` but this for example will keep the errors and markdown with maybe you don't want. To remove all input cells, not only code cells you could use `document.querySelectorAll("jp-Cell jp-CodeCell jp-Notebook-cell").forEach(function(a){a.remove()})` but is a method to check which columns you want and remove them checking the name of the div.

Comment: This works now `document.querySelectorAll("div.jp-Cell.jp-CodeCell.jp-Notebook-cell>.jp-Cell-inputWrapper").forEach(function(a){a.remove()})`

Answer (score 10):

Here is how I do it:
I simply download my notebook as html.

Then run this python script to convert that html file so that prompts and code cells are gone:

```
FILE = "/somewhere/myHTMLFile.html"

with open(FILE, 'r') as html_file:
    content = html_file.read()

# Get rid off prompts and source code
content = content.replace("div.input_area {","div.input_area {\n\tdisplay: none;")    
content = content.replace(".prompt {",".prompt {\n\tdisplay: none;")

f = open(FILE, 'w')
f.write(content)
f.close()
```

That script bascially adds the CSS 'display: none' attribute for all divs of class 'prompt' or 'input_area'.

Comment: Just want to thank you for this code. I have used many 'janky' ways of removing the input areas and prompts, and none are as simple and clean as this. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much! This is definitely the easiest way, and works like a charm!

Answer (score 8):

As a generalization of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45029786/3393574), so that *hidecode* template could be accessible from multiple locations:

1. Go into your home directory:

   ```
   cd ~/.jupyter
   ```
2. Create `jupyter_nbconvert_config.py` under this directory.
3. Write the following into the `.py` file (Change `user_name` to your user name):

   ```
   c = get_config()
   c.TemplateExporter.template_path = ['.', "~/.jupyter" ]
   c.LatexExporter.template_path = ['.', "~/.jupyter"]
   ```
4. Create a template file under this directory, named `hidecode.tplx` or `hidecode.tpl`:

   ```
       ((*- extends 'article.tplx' -*))

   ((* block input_group *))
       ((*- if cell.metadata.get('nbconvert', {}).get('show_code', False) -*))
               ((( super() )))
       ((*- endif -*))
   ((* endblock input_group *))
   ```
5. Then, the following should generate a PDF without `.ipynb` files' codes (Change `file_name` to your file name):

   ```
   jupyter nbconvert --to pdf '<file_name>.ipynb' --template=hidecode.tpl
   ```

Answer (score 7):

You can add this css to your page and then print into PDF from the browser. Note that the code is only hidden, not removed.

```
div.output_prompt { visibility: hidden; }
*{ font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif !important }
.input,#header { display: none; }
```

To make sure you remove the code you should use something like

```
$(".input").remove()
```

As far as I know there is no way to generate via latex a PDF that does not include the code. It would be great to have a jupyter notebook extension that does it though...

Answer (score 3):

`nbconvert` uses templates to convert the notebook's JSON into a document; for example, in the markdown template that comes with nbconvert, `markdown.tpl`:

```
{% block input %}
{% if nb.metadata.language_info %}{{ nb.metadata.language_info.name }}{% endif %}
{{ cell.source}}
{% endblock input %}
```

which prints each cell's source in the output.  If you delete `{{ cell.source}}` then the cell source will not print out. There are corresponding blocks in the HTML and Latex templates as well.

Better yet, make your own template that does exactly what you want :)

Comment: Where is that template located at? Or if I want to use another one, should I specify the new template as a parameter to the jupyter nbconvert command?

Comment: https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/blob/master/nbconvert/templates/markdown.tpl for the stock template - it should be installed with nbconvert somewhere on your python path. I usually specify templates in a config file, but there's a CLI argument also IIRC.