# LaTeX error related to tcolorbox.sty not found

Tags: jupyter-notebook, latex, jupyter

I have a problem with LaTeX whenever I try to download the file in PDF. 
When I try to do that, it gives me the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `tcolorbox.sty' not found.
Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed ,or enter new name.
(Default extension: sty)Enter file name:! Emergency stop.<read > \usepackage
```

I've already downloaded the *tcolorbox* zip file and dragged the directory into the tex/latex tree, as said in README file, but neither that worked.

Originally I used to try to download the pdf from Jupiter Notebook, but also that gave me an error:

```
nbconvert failed: PDF creating failed, captured latex output:
Failed to run "xelatex .\notebook.tex -quiet" command:
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019/W32TeX) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
! Undefined control sequence.
<*> .\notebook
              .tex -quiet
? 
! Emergency stop.
<*> .\notebook
              .tex -quiet
No pages of output.
Transcript written on ?.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 44):

After installing `tcolorbox` using LaTex's package manager `tlmgr`, I was getting similar errors for other dependencies. The solution below worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04 (64 bit) at the terminal:

```
tlmgr update --all --self
tlmgr install tcolorbox
tlmgr install pgf
tlmgr install xcolor
tlmgr install environ
tlmgr install trimspaces
tlmgr install mathpazo
tlmgr install parskip
tlmgr install adjustbox
tlmgr install collectbox
tlmgr install eurosym
tlmgr install ecs
tlmgr install ucs
tlmgr install enumitem
tlmgr install ulem
tlmgr install mathrsfs
tlmgr install jknapltx rsfs
sudo tlmgr install collection-fontsrecommended
```

Also, rendering the document to PDF using the "export notebook as" option didn't work for me. I did it at the command line: `jupyter nbconvert --to pdf my_document.ipynb`. You may need to install [nbconvert](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) if you don't have it.

If missing other dependencies, keep running `tlmgr install` with the missing dependencies until it works. I haven't figured out yet to which packages those dependencies belong, so my apologies for the dirty fix.

Comment: This worked. I also had to install: `sudo tlmgr install titling`

Comment: mad grinder lol but worked for me too! (also had to install titling)

Comment: I had to install upquote and titling: `tlmgr install upquote titling`

ecs and mathrsfs were not found for me

Comment: I installed them one by one looking at the error between them. The list wasn't exactly the same. For Archlinux/Manjaro, look at Praveen's answer.

Comment: Any solution for Windows?

Comment: I havent teoed natively kn Windows. Though, you can use WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux), install Conda, create a dedicated environment, and install dependencies as per the instructions above.

Comment: In case anyone has the same issues with tlmgr as I did (as a Mac and R Studio user) I had a conversation about the tlmgr path connecting to TinyTex (R package) instead of the MacTeX TeX Live 2023 repo: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/708120/tlmgr-configured-to-tinytext-r-instillation-and-not-tex-live-2023. This solution did help (changed my error), but I still get a new error about a LaTeX "Undefined control sequence" that aborts the conversion after attempting to access etoolbox.sty. I've got no complete solution for that yet, just workarounds with xelatex file.tex instead of Jupyter.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to Oscar's answer, I also had to run:

```
sudo tlmgr install collection-fontsrecommended
```

and it worked

Comment: Added it to my response above. Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

Arch/Manjaro users, get the `tllocalmgr` and follow [Oscar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59851436/11404700)

```
    yay -S tllocalmgr-git
    tllocalmgr update --all --self
    tllocalmgr install <package_name>
    sudo texhash
```

Answer (score 4):

Similar error on mac os. In my case, it was related to required packages not being installed in tlmgr.

I had to run

```
sudo tlmgr install tcolorbox
```

After fixing that, the same error appeared with other packages (e.g. `environ`). I kept installing each missing package

```
sudo tlmgr install {name_of_missing_package}
```

until it succeeded.

Comment: For me, specifically this lot: tcolorbox, environ, pdfcol, adjustbox, titling, enumitem, soul, refs, times

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same issue on Fedora

running

```
dnf install texlive-collection-latexextra
```

Seemed solved the issue for me. I found this guide [How to fully install Latex in fedora?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/199641) to be particularly helpful in debugging my issues. It gave all the commands needed to install the latex packages I needed

Answer (score 0):

Following tsando's advice on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36916093/convert-ipynb-to-pdf-in-jupyter/52498741#52498741) stack overflow post, I just had to add this to my ~/.zshrc file after installing MacTex,

```
# TeX
export PATH=/Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/texbin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

On RHEL 9 with nbconvert 6.5.4 from Anaconda 2023.09, I first had to install these packages from the base RHEL repositories:

```
sudo dnf install texlive-adjustbox texlive-bibtex texlive-eurosym \
  texlive-jknapltx texlive-lm-math texlive-parskip texlive-rsfs \
  texlive-titling texlive-ulem texlive-upquote texlive-xetex
```

Then these non-RHEL packages from [EPEL 9](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/epel/):

```
sudo dnf install pandoc texlive-tcolorbox
```

These pulled in all the required dependencies for nbconvert to convert notebooks to PDF.