# Jupyter Lab not succeeding in exporting to PDF

Tags: pdf, jupyter, fedora, jupyter-lab

I am trying to export some `.ipynb` document to a PDF one.

But I get the `500 : Internal Server Error`. There are a lot of `LaTeX` errors but I have not used `LaTeX` at all in this notebook.

Seems some component is missing in the exporting process.

I am running Fedora 31.

To what should I look for to fix this? Should I install some more packages?

Comment: If you are seeing LaTeX errors (and you "don't use LaTeX"), either some piece is missing (Did you install Jupyter from the official repositories? That would pull in the required pieces) or something else is very broken. See if you can coax it into spitting out other formats, e.g. LaTeX, and work from there.

Comment: Yes, I installed it using `dnf`.  I see no reason for it to be broken.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59225719/latex-error-related-to-tcolorbox-sty-not-found/59851436#59851436). That worked for me.