# How to collapse code cells in Google Cloud Datalab?

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

Is there a way to collapse some code cells in Google Cloud Datalab?
This [S/O question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934885/how-to-hide-code-from-cells-in-ipython-notebook-visualized-with-nbviewer) has a few solutions to collapses all code cells.
It would be nice if I could collapse only a couple code cells (functions, init code...) and that this info would be saved inside the .ipynb file.

Answer (score 0):

Not presently, no. If there are features you think are missing please open issues in the github repo, thanks!