# how to run jupyter notebook from 5th cell to 100th cell, without running other part of the notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter

Say I have a jupyter nootebook with 200 cells.

how to run from 5th cell to 100th cell, without running other part of the notebook?

Now I commend out 101th-200th and 1st-4th cell. I'm sure it is not the best practise.

Comment: @JGreenwell that's right..but how to skip the first 5?

Comment: Added an answer showing the best method that I have found

Comment: Use mouse's shift click to select multiple cells by clicking `In [37]`, https://github.com/jupyter/help/issues/68#issuecomment-370518110

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One cannot just run cells 5 thru 100 easily with the Jupyter notebook but there are a few options. The first is just selecting each cell and running *Merge Cell Above* from the edit menu then just running the new cell. The second, and best way I've found to do this is:

1. First select the top cells to be ignored (or bottom if there are less on the bottom) and change the *Cell Type* to *Raw NBConvert* to prevent IPython from interpreting it.

[image: jupyter notebook menu Cell->Cell Type->Raw NB]

2. Go to the cell after the one you want to run and select *Run All Above* (or below if less there).

[image: menu Cell->Run All Above]

Now you've only run those middle cells and can just go back and reset the cell type to code (instead of having to comment and then un-comment) and keep going.

* If you are using NBViewer you can [hide the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934885/how-to-hide-code-from-cells-in-ipython-notebook-visualized-with-nbviewer) or just set it to *Markdown*

Answer (score 1):

Another option which requires less mouse movement and clicks than JGreenwell's answer, especially if you prefer accomplishing this with speedy keyboard work like I would:

1. Click in cell #1
2. Select all code (`Ctrl+A`)
3. Comment-out code (`Ctrl+/`)
4. Go to next cell (`Shift+Enter`) -- will execute cell, but is meaningless since all code is commented
5. Repeat steps 2-4 until cell #5
6. Select cell #200 and select *Run All Above*
7. Go back and un-comment cell 1-5 (`Ctrl+A`, `Ctrl+/`)

You can easily move between cells using the keyboard: Press `Esc` (command mode), Press `J` (up) or `K` (down) to select adjacent cell. Press `Enter` (to enter the code). Then press `Ctrl+A` then `Ctrl+/` to un-comment. Repeat from `Esc`.