# Is there a way to hide code in individual cells in ipython notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I know one can hide the code in the entire notebook - just looked at this question and magnificent answer [How to hide code from cells in ipython notebook visualized with nbviewer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934885/how-to-hide-code-from-cells-in-ipython-notebook-visualized-with-nbviewer) - but can one do that for individual notebook cells?

Comment: You can with nbconvert and a custom template - have a look at https://github.com/michaelpacer/hiding_tags_nbconvert

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I took a quick look and am not sure yet on how to use it. If you have a quick example to post, that would be great.

Comment: At the moment there's no way to use custom templates with nbviewer, so it would have to be at the command line. The README in that repo has an example for using it at the command line.