# How can I remove or disable an ipywidget's widget clear button in a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I'm trying to write a simple user interface for Python code in a Jupyter/IPython notebook. I'm using the amazing [ipywidgets](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I need to find a way to prevent users from clearing the widgets by accidentally clicking the `<button class="close">×</button>` (the `X` to the left of the widgets). I've spent hours searching for a simple way to do this. Here's a simple, minimal example of the issue in a single Jupyter notebook cell:

```
import ipywidgets
import IPython.display

w = ipywidgets.IntSlider()

IPython.display.display(w)
```

The result is a slider with the widget clear button `X` to the left of the slider:

[Image of slider with widget clear button `X`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvuDx.png)

How can I remove or disable the widget clear button so that the user can't accidentally clear the widget?

Comment: Look into custom styling the widget, or apply a javascript hack to hide it?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking into the same problem and solved it by some hack. So dropping off my solution here:

In your running notebook, run this code in a cell:

```
from IPython.display import HTML

htmlscript_ipywidget_disable_closing = '''<script>
disable = true
function disable_ipyw_close(){
    if(disable){
        $('div.widget-area > div.prompt > button.close').hide()
    }
    else{
        $('div.widget-area > div.prompt > button.close').show()    
    }
    disable = !disable
}
$( document ).ready(disable_ipyw_close);
</script>

<form action="javascript:disable_ipyw_close()"><input style="opacity: 0.5" type="submit" value="Disable ipywidget closing"></form>'''
# change opacity to 0 to hide this button itself
HTML(htmlscript_ipywidget_disable_closing)
```

A Button will appear in the output which will toggle the visibility of those ipywidget close buttons.
This was heavily inspired by the top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934885), which was about hiding all input cells.