# Jupyter Notebook: Hide / fold a paragraph of text as "hints"

Tags: html, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am using a Jupyter Notebook for an interactive coding demonstration. There is an exercises block where the user should enter their own code to try and solve a problem.

I now want to optionally give some further instructions, i.e. hints how to solve the problem, which should be hidden by default.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47017746/4792865), which links to this [site here](http://chris-said.io/2016/02/13/how-to-make-polished-jupyter-presentations-with-optional-code-visibility/), using JavaScript in a raw nbconvert cell to hide output cells. However, this only seems to work for exported notebooks, while I want something in the notebook itself.
So I've tried adding similar JS into a Markdown cell, but that doesn't work because the JS gets sanitized away.

I'm not sure if CSS also gets sanitized, but raw HTML works. Is there a good way to create a hidden/folded text paragraph with something like "click here for further instructions" to show the text?

The best I could come up with so far was a `title` attribute to create a mouse-over text, unfortunately without further formatting:

`<span title="Instruction text goes here">Mouse over for further instructions</span>`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `<details>` tag is pure HTML which does just that, and which does not get removed by the sanitizer. It can have a `<summary>` to describe the contents of the fold.

```
<details>
<summary>Click here for instructions</summary>
Instructions go here
</details>
```

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details

Comment: Thanx! To extend check link or consider e.g.: .... `<summary><font color='blue'>
  Click here for instructions
</font> </summary>`