# How can I make a presentable PDF from a Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I know that I can click on `File -> Print Preview` and let my browser save the result as a PDF. But that PDF will contain quite a bit of code.

Can I hide parts from the print preview or make a PDF with another tool?

Ideally, there would be magic functions:

- `%hide`: Hide the cell and its output
- `%hide-code`: Hide only the code of the cell, but show the output of the code

Answer (score 5):

## Print to PDF in the browser

In JupyterLab, you can hide the cell's input and output by clicking the side bar as demonstrated in the [doc](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/notebook.html?highlight=collapse). After hiding, you can use the browser's printing menu to generate a PDF. I've tested it on FireFox and expect similar result on Chrome or Edge.

[image]

## Export to PDF with `nbconvert`

If you aim at a native conversion from `ipynb` format to `pdf`, the nice old `nbconvert` tool is your friend.  It usually comes together with Jupyter and can be invoked conveniently in the menu of JupyterLab `File->Export Notebook As...->PDF` or, in the classic Jupyter Notebook interface, `File->Download as->PDF (via LaTeX)`. 
Hiding input/output in cells can be realized by setting the cell's metadata `hide_input=true` and installing a [nbextension](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/hide_input/readme.html) as discussed in [issue #155](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/155).

## Print Preview menu in the classical Jupyter

Finally to your question

> Can I hide parts from the print preview or make a PDF with another tool?

The "print preview" button in the classical Jupyter interface is a shortcut for calling `nbconvert` to generate a HTML file and redirect your browser to it. Therefore, similar configuration for `nbconvert` to hide input as discussed above (in issue #155) can be used. This feature is implemented by `jupyter_contrib_nbextensions` bundle and explained in the [doc](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/exporting.html#jupyter_contrib_nbextensions.nbconvert_support.CodeFoldingPreprocessor).

Answer (score 3):

As the above-mentioned answers do not work for me; I found another solution:

I use an additional package `notebook-as-pdf`.

Read the [tutorial here](https://towardsdatascience.com/jupyter-notebook-to-pdf-in-a-few-lines-3c48d68a7a63). It uses Chromium and is the only approach that worked for me so far reliably. The "print preview" does still not work. But it produces a clean PDF with no code input.

I do:

1. `pip install -U notebook-as-pdf`
2. `pyppeteer-install`
3. `jupyter nbconvert --to PDFviaHTML --TemplateExporter.exclude_input=True PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE.ipynb`

What did NOT work for me:

1. The solution above.
2. All the scripts mentioned in [those answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934885/how-to-hide-code-from-cells-in-ipython-notebook-visualized-with-nbviewer)