# Hide code cells in Jupyter Notebook, execute with Papermill, transform to PDF with nbconvert

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert, papermill

I want to run a `python` program (not command line) using `papermill` to execute a `jupyter` notebook and then transform it into a PDF. The idea is working, but I'm unable to hide the input cells.

For `papermill` `report_mode = True` is supposed to hide input cells, but there seems to be a problem with `jupyter` Classic (https://github.com/nteract/papermill/issues/130)

Other extension like hide_input or html scripts are also not sufficient.
Maybe a `nbconvert` template for hide cells is a solution, but I didn't get that running.

My minimal Code:

```
pm.execute_notebook(
        "Input.ipynb",
        "Output.ipynb",
        parameters=dict(id=id),
        report_mode=True,
    )
notebook_filename = "Output.ipynb"

with open(notebook_filename) as f:
    nb = nbformat.read(f, as_version=4)
pdf_exporter = PDFExporter()
pdf_data, resources = pdf_exporter.from_notebook_node(nb)
```

So I'm looking for a way to execute the Notebook, hide the input cells and transform the Notebook to a PDF. I want to use `nbconvert` in `Python` and not as a command line tool, since the Script shall run daily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you said you "don't want to use command line", but how about having your python script execute a `subprocess` command after running `papermill`? Mixing with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50790330/3923163):

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call('jupyter nbconvert --to pdf --TemplateExporter.exclude_input=True Output.ipynb')
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, could work with some twerking. I had issues with the Shell / Interpreter trying the approach.


The solution I found is, to just add the line:  


`pdf_exporter.exclude_input = True`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing one small detail in your code:

```py
pm.execute_notebook(
        "Input.ipynb",
        "Output.ipynb",
        parameters=dict(id=id),
        report_mode=True,
    )
notebook_filename = "Output.ipynb"

with open(notebook_filename) as f:
    nb = nbformat.read(f, as_version=4)
pdf_exporter = PDFExporter()

# add this
pdf_exporter.exclude_input = True

pdf_data, resources = pdf_exporter.from_notebook_node(nb)
```

You can also use [Ploomber](https://github.com/ploomber/ploomber) for this; it has a few benefits, like running notebooks in parallel:

```py
# convert.py

from pathlib import Path
from ploomber import DAG
from ploomber.tasks import NotebookRunner
from ploomber.products import File
from ploomber.executors import Parallel

dag = DAG(executor=Parallel())

# hide input and convert to PDF using the LaTeX converter
NotebookRunner(
    Path('input.ipynb'),
    File('output-latex.pdf'),
    dag=dag,
    # do not include input code (only cell's output)
    nbconvert_export_kwargs={'exclude_input': True},
    name='latex')

# hide input and convert to PDF using the web PDF converter (no need to install LaTeX!
NotebookRunner(
    Path('input.ipynb'),
    File('output-web.pdf'),
    dag=dag,
    # do not include input code (only cell's output)
    nbconvert_export_kwargs={'exclude_input': True},
    # use webpdf converter
    nbconvert_exporter_name='webpdf',
    name='web')

# generate both PDFs
if __name__ == '__main__':
    dag.build()
```

*Note:* as of Ploomber 0.20, notebooks must have a "parameters" cell (you can add an empty one). [See instructions here.](https://papermill.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage-parameterize.html)

To run it:

```bash
pip install ploomber
python convert.py
```