# Exiting ipywidgets interact / interactive to produce a final output in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ipywidgets

I'd like to have an analogy to the `%matplotlib notebook` magic for `matplotlib` plots. It features a "power button" at the top right - and after clicking it, the UI disappears, and the output becomes a PNG of the final view.

Suppose I have a function to filter a dataframe using a value from an int slider:

```
from ipywidgets import interact
# df = pd.read_csv('...')

@interact(zone=(-1, 12))
def show(zone):
    if zone > 0:
        return df[df.ZoneId == zone]  # show filtered results

    if zone == 0:
        return df  # show all results

    # HERE: I want to exit the interaction, and make the int slider disappear, and the whole
    # of df to become the rendered output
```

I have tried creating the slider and bind it to something:

```
zone_slider = IntSlider(0, -1, 12)
@interact(zone=zone_slider)
def show(zone):
    # ...
    zone_slider.close()  # slider disappears, but output is still the same `interactive`.
```

I'd like the output to be saved with the notebook, and (after closing the notebook and opening it with a new kernel) to be displayed without the need to run any code (nor doing the interaction). Right now it only gets displayed as `intearctive(children=[IntSlider(...), Output(...)], ...)`.

I'd like a general solution (finishing any interaction, when e.g. a `Checkbox` becomes `True`). I'm not sure if it's possible to do without resorting to lower level `ipywidgets.interactive` function or `interact_manual`, but I don't know how to use these anyway.

Comment: I'm not following what you want.  I don't understand how the first paragraph of your question relates to the rest.  Actually, if I understand it right, it seems like you're making two questions here: 1 - How do you programmatically remove the UI and leave only the outputs, and 2 - how do you keep the interactive output on the saved notebook, instead of '`interactive(children...`'.  Is that right?  Or you're interested in only one of the two parts?  Or did I get it completely wrong?

Comment: Yes, I want the interactive to go away and be replaced by a `IPython.display(<value returned from the decorated function)`. The reference to MPL is only because their `notebook` backend does something similar. I have contacted `ipywidgets` authors, and they said such a way does not currently exist (so I wasted a bounty... tough luck). However, saving the widgets' state goes a long way toward having a "visible result" when the notebook opens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 1 - How do you programmatically remove the UI and leave only the outputs

You can adapt [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28073228/8280541) to hide/show the widgets.  On the `code_toggle` function, you can add code like this:

```
$('div.widget-slider').hide();
```

You'll have to do it for each type of widget you use.  Don't forget to add `.show()` as well.

## 2 - how do you keep the interactive output on the saved notebook, instead of `'interactive(children...'`.

I found a more specific question for that, which was unanswered, and I answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59241644/8280541).  Basically, it is a hack to call the action from the menu item *Widgets* → *Save Notebook Widget State*.