# jupyter notebook does not render images/plots when saved as html

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

The sample contents of my Jupyter Notebook as Markdown text are as follows:

```
<img src="files/metrics/metric1.png">
```

Although, this gets nicely rendered in the same notebook. But when I download the file as HTML and try to open it at a different location (where the folder metrics is not there), it is blank. The use-case is to share all the plots in a notebook with a team member. How can this be fixed? Or is there any similar way of sharing the notebook where I don't want to see the jupyter code cells but just the plots in my final output?

Comment: You can hide the code cells with this approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/28073228/13520068

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for the first question: downloading the html page with plots contained inside it?