# How to keep all code collapsed permanently in Jupyter Notebook 7+

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I used to hide all code from a Jupyter notebook by just running a piece of JS code (as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28073228/3199664)

However, this solution doesn't work on new versions of Jupyter notebooks. Instead, the function View > Collapse All Code can be used to hide code. The problem with this solution is that code isn't permanently hidden (if you click on a cell, the code is displayed).
This can be annoying when you want to keep the code hidden.

Is there a solution to force the code collapse? Thanks!

Comment: "Is there a solution to force the code collapse?" Given the title I think you mean no matter what the user does.  .... I think this might be the case where the developers would argue current behavior is a feature & not a bug: those familiar with Jupyter should be able to opt in to seeing the cell by clicking on the code cell. If you want to keep the code in the notebook hidden from users you should be using [Voila](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila) to render the notebook so that the code is not visible. You can see running examples from the [Voila Gallery](https://voila-gallery.org/).

Comment: <conitnued> Alternatively,  you can continue to use the older style interface where that approach you like continues to work. (I just tried it and verified for NbClassic ver 1.0.0.) You are looking for NbClassic, see my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76837597/8508004) for a good resource for reading more about that offering.

Comment: This post would be better titled as 'How to keep all code collapsed permanently in Jupyter Notebook 7+', and would help others going forward find it. You currently have "new versions of Jupyter notebooks" and people have to work backwards to sort what you mean.

Comment: thanks for your replies. I don't mean "no matter what the user does" but the current behavior of displaying the code as soon as the cell is clicked is a bit annoying. Having one button that keeps everything collapsed unless you click on it was pretty convenient

Answer (score 1):

The most direct way to continue to use your approach is to switch to using NbClassic. This is the way the Jupyter developers are currently planning to offer support for the older interface and tech that works with that as development continues on the project's main development fronts (JupyterLab and Jupyter Notebook 7+) relying on what is the current JupyterLab tech under the engine. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76837597/8508004) for more about the NbClassic offering. Jupyter Notebook 7+ is meant to be the document-centric offering to replace the older interface.

Alternatively, you can use [Voila](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila) alongside Jupyter Notebook 7+ and/or JupyterLab to offer renderings of active running notebooks that doesn't show the underlying code.  You can see running examples from [the Voila Gallery](https://voila-gallery.org/). Or, currently, you can launch running examples served by HuggingFace using the demo link at the bottom of [this post on the Jupyter blog site](https://blog.jupyter.org/voil%C3%A0-0-5-0-homecoming-66f2465aa86f) about Voila being improved to run using the JupyterLab tech underlying JupyterLab 4 and current Jupyter Notebook 7.