# HTML not working in latest version of jupyter notebook

Tags: python, html, jupyter

I had a working code that used to hide all code in Jupyter via a button click so that only the output was visible, however on replicating the code in the latest version of Jupyter I still see the button but clicking on it does nothing. Any ideas?

```
from IPython.display import Javascript, display, HTML
from ipywidgets import widgets

HTML('''<script>
code_show=true; 
function code_toggle() {
 if (code_show){
 $('div.input').hide();
 } else {
 $('div.input').show();
 }
 code_show = !code_show
} 
$( document ).ready(code_toggle);
</script>
<form action="javascript:code_toggle()"><input type="submit" value="Toggle on/off code"></form>''')
```

Comment: "in latest version of jupyter notebook"? You need to specify what that means to you. I assume you mean Jupyter Notebook 7+ and so that should be somewhere here in your post. Anyway, I'll try to find where someone already asked this question. Part of the issue is that wasn't a supported feature and was sort of a hack folks used. There is now a way to 'collapse' all code in the newer version of Jupyter Notebook 7+. You can toggle the state at any time too. (Or for only certain cells individually.) That state is stored in the meta tag of the cell & will ...

Comment: <continued> be respected when you or others re-open your Jupyter `.ipynb` file. You can access the collapse controls from under 'View'  along the 'File' menu at the top of Jupyter Notebook 7+. You can toggle the state of individual code cells by clicking on the bar that comes up to the left side of where the brackets are if you hover over there with your mouse. Jupyter Notebook 7+ is built on JupyterLab components and so methods that work in JupyterLab 3.4+ and 4+ tend to be the way to work in Jupyter Notebook 7+ and so sometimes knowing that and including JupyterLab in the terms helps ...

Comment: <continued> when searching around the internet for current approaches. If a lot of what I've said is new to you, you may want to read about the latest changes in the Jupyter ecosystem. A good place to start is using resources I have listed in the bottom half of [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76837597/8508004). Note to see the top half of my answer there if you prefer to keep things as they are. You can choose for now to instead use the latest version of NbClassic that keeps things as-is for now. One drawback is that eventually NbClassic will not be supported or ....

Comment: <continued> lack current abilities you'll want. So you are only kicking the can down the road for some time before you'll hit this issue later. You have to choose specifically to install NbClassic if you wish to use it. There's also Voila that hides all code as it lets things run in more like an app mode. You develop the Jupyter `.ipynb` file in Jupyter Notebook 7+ or JupyterLab but when it is rendered no code is displayed and it cannot easily be toggled by you or someone else in the Voila rendering. You or they can though use the notebook mode if they know how to switch modes.

Comment: This has been asked and covered [here in the post entitled 'How to keep all code collapsed permanently in Jupyter Notebook 7+'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77244850/8508004). I'd prefer to keep that as the main place for related discussion as it came first.